# Why is Access Database coming up with a syntax error for my select statement in my where clause?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am quite new to access database and can't wrap my head around why a syntax error keeps popping up every time I try to run this query, I hope that you're able to help

```Sql
    SELECT Customer.forename, Customer.surname
    FROM Customer, Booking
    WHERE Booking.customerID=Customer.CustomerID AND Booking.childTicket=(SELECT 
    MAX(Booking.childTicket))
    GROUP BY Customer.forename, Customer.surname;
```

The error says: Syntax error in query expression `Booking.customerID=Customer.CustomerID AND Booking.childTicket=(SELECT MAX(Booking.childTicket))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide a complete subquery:

```
WHERE Booking.customerID=Customer.CustomerID AND Booking.childTicket=
(SELECT MAX(Booking.childTicket) FROM Booking)
```

Comment: Ohh interesting, didn't think about that, thank you very much!